# Hadoop Connection Refused exception without any reason

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, connection-refused

I was able to execute this and other commands;
  `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://101-master:50000`

I rebooted my cloud instances from OpenStack horizon web interface and started getting this exception for no reason. I did not make any changes to the configuration:

Call From 101-master/192.168.0.18 to 101-master:50000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

what is the reason for this exception.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you add the stacktrace.. then we can say due to what reason it's happening.. without any traces, just by ConnectionRefused message, one can't say.. because it happens in so many scenarios with many reasons..

Comment: This is the command the result of the command. I don't have any more details about it. ----------------------------ubuntu@101-master:~$ hadoop fs -ls
15/01/29 13:49:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Call From 101-master/192.168.0.18 to 101-master:50000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: How can I get more verbose stack trace for  the command ubuntu@101-master:~$ hadoop fs -ls?

Comment: `HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console hadoop fs -ls /` will give you full stacktrace.. And share in the question, configuration files and namenode log files error stack trace..

Comment: Thanks for the help. The node was disconnected due to some network issue.